# MongoMapper and NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongomapper

I have the two models as seen below. An instance of `Share` may have multiple instances of `Color`. I'm using MongoMapper to manage these models.
When I do `Share.create`, I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Color

Can anyone tell me why this is?

/models/share.rb:

```
class Share
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :shorten_id, String
  key :name, String
  many :colors, :class_name => "Color"
  timestamps!
end
```

/models/color.rb:

```
class Color
   include MongoMapper::Document

   key :celcius, Float
   key :hue, Float
   key :saturation, Float
   key :brightness, Float
   belongs_to :share, :class_name => "Share"
   timestamps!
end
```

This is where I try to create the instances:

/routes/api.rb:

```
require 'json'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace

  namespace '/api' do
    before do
      protected!
    end

    get '/shares' do
      content_type 'application/json'
      Share.all.to_json
    end

    post '/share' do
      @share = Share.create
      @share.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I could not have a model named `Color`. I guess it's a reserved name. Changing it to `ShareColor` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sinatra, you need to load all the models you use manually via a `require` statement. `require` [loads a file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) and executes all its statements, but also makes sure the same file is not loaded twice.

Comment: if you can't fit everything into a single file you're project might be too big for sinatra. Otherwise as above, you need to require.

Comment: @Lukas_Skywalker I can't figure out where I need to `require`. Now I have required the `Color` model in the `Share` model and vice versa. In `api.rb` I have required both of them but I get the same error.

Comment: @three I guess I can fit everything into a single file I just like the structure better when I keep everything in separate files.